# Ext JS 4: Custom object property value based on condition

Tags: object, extjs, properties, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create custom property values (based on a condition of a function) for my Ext objects, instead of specifying just a value.

**Example 1:**

***old code (working)***

```
        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
```

[image]

***new code (not working)***

```
        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: function() {
                    return 'Save X';
                },
```

[image]

**Example 2:**

***old code (working)***

```
                    }, {
                        width: 270,
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'user_id', 
                        fieldLabel: 'User ID',
                        hidden: true
                    }]
```

***new code (not working)***

```
                    }, {
                        width: 270,
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'user_id', 
                        fieldLabel: 'User ID',
                        hidden: function() { return true; }
                    }]
```

**Example 3:**

Ignore entire *textfield* object (lazy instance) completely based on a condition:

```
                    }, {
                        width: 270,
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'employee_number', 
                        fieldLabel: 'Employee Number'
                    }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't do it this way. It is not possible to replace a type with a function. In your case you assign a function reference to a variable which is expected to be boolean, same for the string.

**Solution A.**

You should consider to write yourself a field factory. Within that factory you can then execute any function before assigning configs. (Sort of same then B but can be used to reduce function calls)

**Solution B.**

Use a function reference itself. This one should then get executed. (spare the requirement of class extension and is over that reuseable)

```
 // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});
Ext.namespace('my.util.helper');
my.util.helper.decideHide = function() { return true; }

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
       xtype: 'combo',
       fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
       store: states,
       queryMode: 'local',
       displayField: 'name',
       valueField: 'abbr',
       test: my.util.helper.decideHide(),
       listeners: {
           afterrender: function(n) {
               alert(n.test);
           }
        }
    }]
});
```

**Solution C.**

And the solution I use most in such cases are simplified if else statements

```
// ... // more code
{
    text: myCondition ? 'Text A' : 'Text B',
    // more code
}
// ... // more code
```

Comment: Solution A is overkill imo.  Solution B won't currently work as it's coded.  `decideHide` is a function that is never executed.  Solution C doesn't use functions.

Comment: I must admit you are totally right in case that Solution B want work this way without global scope

Comment: Talking about Solution C: if possible any unrequired function call should be spared. This is most critical within loops but if I check just one condition there is no need calling a function for this. The bigger the application is the more these tiny things helps keeping performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is not going to work, some Ext configs take a function that will be evaluated but most of them don't.  Instead of creating anonymous functions and not invoking them I would do something like this:

```
Ext.define('UserPanel', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    initComponent : function() {

        this.items = [{
            xtype : 'button',
            text : this._getSaveButtonText()
        }, {
            width : 270,
            labelAlign : 'right',
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'user_id',
            fieldLabel : 'User ID',
            hidden : this._isUserIdHidden()
        }]
        this.callParent();
    },

    _getSaveButtonText : function() {
        return 'Save';
    },

    _isUserIdHidden : function() {
        return true;
    }
});
```